# Display Data According to City in CakePHP 3x

Tags: cakephp

I have a business listing site based on CakePHP 3x. I want to display business on the home page based on City Selected. Table Store has [city_id] and Table Cities have [id] in common.

in Header File we got selected city

```
<option <?php if($selected_city_item == $val['id']){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>  value="<?php echo $val['id']; ?>" data-value="<?php echo $val['city_slug']; ?>"><?php echo $val['city'] ?></option><?php } ?>
```

and we try to filter like this in IndexController

```
$sqlFeaturedStore = "SELECT s.`id`,s.`biz_name`,s.`biz_slug`,img_1`, st.`state`,c.`city`,c.`city_slug`,a.`area`,ul.id AS ul_id,ul.user_id,ul.store_id,IF(ul.user_id IS NOT NULL , '1', '0') AS isFavourite FROM tbl_stores s LEFT JOIN tbl_states st ON st.id = s.state_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_cities c ON s.`city_id` = c.`id`
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_areas a ON s.`area_id` = a.`id`
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user_likes ul ON s.id = ul.store_id AND ul.user_id = '".$user_id."'
                    WHERE s.`featured` = '1'
                    AND s.`status`='1'
                    AND s.`state_id` = st.`id`
                    AND s.`city_id` = c.`id`
                    AND s.`area_id` = a.`id`
                    AND s.city_id = c.`city` = '" . $selected_city_item . "'
                    ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 0,4";
```

but this not working. Is anyone here to help.

Comment: Possible SQL injection vulnerabilities (never insert data into queries directly if it can be avoided) and not using the form helper, that's not off to a good start ;-) That being said, please be a little more specific, "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, describe what _exactly_ is happening, and what _exactly_ you expect to happen instead - thanks!

Comment: thanks, ndm for your suggestion, I am new to programming. In Simple words. I want to display businesses mark as featured according to the city in which they are registered. Currently showing any business in any city.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got a notification about the reply. So, your problem is with the query I guess, and not with the values passed to it? On a quick look the condition for `city_id` is wrong, as you are assigning the result of a boolean expression eg the result of `city = selected city item`, which will always be either `0` or `1`.